# On Report viewer can't watch the data

Tags: .net, vb.net, dataset, report

I have a report viewer in a form, and when I run the project I want to watch the values from the fields which they are coming from a DataSet.

The Dataset comes in full into my form. I have install the Report Viewer as Microsoft says BUT!!!

No Values.

Why is that?

Comment: Please use the `Windows` tag only for issues specifically relating to Windows, and the `Visual-Studio-2010` tag only for issues relating directly to the IDE.

Comment: @Greg, Thank you for your remind, you see these two Last weeks I'm in huge pressure in order to release my project on Monday and I was have the need of any assistance I can get from anywhere. But you have right every Tag is for it's own element. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a ReportDataSource which is bound to your DataSet, then bind the Report to the ReportDataSource.

It's hard to give more detailed advice without seeing some code, but [Mahesh Chands tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataSetReports04252007100945AM/DataSetReports.aspx) might help.

Comment: yes I see from the Link you send me the meaning of my next step. But the proposed solution it is not workable. I mean the meaning is to transfer the Dataset into the current DataSourse produced from the Report Wizard thru a mean of transfer. But the mean of use an xml document drives us elsewhere because we already have the DataSet in a Public plase and we can recall it at any time and pass it to the DataSource I thing.

Comment: My humble opinion is that this issue should be covered from visual studio itself and not needs the intervention from developer.

Comment: Now until the end of the Load form event i have all the data i need and i pass them to the proper datasourse (I check it and i see the data there). I let the program to do the refresh report in which I'm expecting to see the data !!!! BUT Nothing. Fields are clear. As no data in there. Please I need an assistance here

Comment: Finally I found what was wrong. And I solve it. Of course from all the above I got only ideas and combined between them. Yes I got the variables. Now I'm trying to fix the document!!!!!